# java second sql statement not working

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm using postgresql and having one problem inserting data into two different tables.

The idea is to insert some data no `tableamizades` and them insert some data in `tablenotify`. Basically a friend request is made and there is a notification associated with that request.

I have this code:

```
01    @Override
02    public void AddFriends(int userMakesRequest, int userReceivesRequest, boolean TrueOrFalse, boolean TrueOrFalse2) {
03        String notificacao, userMakesRequestName;
04        Connection connection = null;
05        Statement stmt = null;
06        ResultSet rs = null;
07
08        try {
09            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
10
11            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:"
12                    + "//localhost:5432/projecto", "postgres", "admin");
13
14            stmt = connection.createStatement();
15            try {
16
17                stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO tableamizades (iduser1,iduser2,amigoaceite1,amigoaceite2) VALUES ( "
18                        + userMakesRequest + " , '" + userReceivesRequest + "' , '" + TrueOrFalse + "' , '"
19                        + TrueOrFalse2 + "');");
20                try {
21
22
23                    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM utilizadores WHERE iduser = '" + userMakesRequest + "';");
24                    rs.next();
25                    userMakesRequestName = rs.getString("username");
26
27                    notificacao = " O utilizador " + userMakesRequestName + " fez-lhe um pedido de amizade";
28
29                    stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO tablenotify (iduser,notificacao) VALUES ( " + userReceivesRequest + " , '" + notificacao + "');");
30                    rs.close();
31
32                } catch (SQLException e) {
33                }
34
35            } catch (SQLException e) {
36            }
37            stmt.close();
38
39            connection.close();
40
41        } catch (Exception e) {
42            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
43        } finally {
44            try {
45                connection.close();
46            } catch (Exception e) {
47                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
48            }
49        }
```

If I do this, the data is insert on `tableamizades` but not on `tablenotify`. I can see that the code for inserting data on `tablenotify` is ok because if i comment out lines 15 to 19 and 35 and 36, the data on `tablenotify` is correctly inserted.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't swallow exceptions like that. Always print them out or log them. With what you have, you don't even know if there's an exception thrown in there.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/java.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several things wrong:

- inserting data must be done with executeUpdate(), and not executeQuery()
- you should learn about [prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which would avoid SQL injection attacks and incorrect queries if your parameters contain characters like quotes, which must be escaped.
- you should not ignore SQLExceptions as you're doing, since they contain the error message which would help identifying the problem. Don't catch those exceptions. If you catch them, throw a runtime exception wrapping them.